# PyBrain: Removing individual connections

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pybrain

How do you remove connections in Pybrain? I'm using the one-neuron-per-module technique to customize connectivity between an input layer, a single hidden layer, and an output layer. But now I'd like to manipulate that connectivity during training, and one such manipulation is to remove a connection/edge.

In the Network class, I see addConnection but no removeConnection function. Is there any nice way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify Connection, replace it with IdentityConnection - https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/blob/master/pybrain/structure/connections/identity.py - I'm not sure 100%.

You may look also at another connection classes.